# How does passthru() work?

Tags: php

I am interested to know what exactly [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) is doing?

I have to create my own function with similar functionality, but I cannot understand how the function works.

Comment: You can refer to PHP sources, rather than ask someone to do it for you. Why do you want to create your own function with similar functionality, why this one doesn't suit you?

Comment: `passthru` is ultimately written in C. Should the answer concern the C internals, or a "PHP level" explanation?

Comment: PHP level please. I have to re-create this functionality in PHP. My goal is to forward the output to any arbitrary file, not just `php://stdout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internals of `passthru` won't help you much, since they're too low-level to be reproducible by PHP.

> My goal is to forward the output to any arbitrary file, not just php://stdout.

If you want to do this on PHP level without first reading the whole output into a variable, I'd suggest something like [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). This lets you open a pointer to a process, from which you can read little by little and write the data to a file little by little (which is actually probably pretty close to what `passthru` does). E.g.:

```
while (($buffer = fread($p, 1024)) !== false) {
    fwrite($file, $buffer);
}
```

If you're working on the command line anyway though, why not just write to a file there?

```
exec('command > file');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `shell_exec` and appending `>> file` to command?

```
function exec_to_file($cmd,$file){
    shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd) . ' >> ' . $file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to display binary data after executing a command?

How would you like to change to standard behaviour?

As far as I know passthru() works similar to exec() and system(), but allows for the processing/display of binary data as well, so my guess would be that it pipes the output from the passthru() command directly to a binary stream.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php.

Comment: `passthru()` sends output to `php://stdout`. I'm interested to forward it to a normal file..

Answer (score 0):

The source to passthru can be found in [ext/standard/exec.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/exec.c?view=markup) - it's actually pretty readable and should be possible to write your own version in PHP directly.

It sounds like what you need to do is simply use [popen](http://php.net/popen) to open a process, then you can just read output from it like any other file handle.